# Extracting the day value from a date

Tags: vb.net

How can I get the day [(value)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh(v=vs.90).aspx) from the today's date? For example it's 17th March 2017. How can I convert this to Friday?

This is how I get my date:

```
Label1.Text = Format(Date.Now, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

It's using that format because thats the format of the date data type in MySQL

Comment: You'll find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN article covers what you want nicely.

Comment: `Label1.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dddd")`

Comment: i tried it but just as `Dim dateValue As Date
        TextBox1.Text = dateValue.ToString("dddd")` but the textbox displays monday

Comment: So obviously `dateValue` contains a date on monday. Which date has it in the debugger?

Comment: `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox1.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dddd")`

answered by Alex B.

Comment: There's no point putting this answer here as, as you already cited, @AlexB. answered it in comments.

Comment: i just post it for viewers to stop posting answer. sorry im new here dont know how things works here